# How to handle flags in response to this user's question history?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915067/what-is-the-greedy-approach-of-this) yesterday for being unclear (could have qualified for others too) and went on my merry way.

Today, in the edit queue, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935304/how-to-prove-this-is-a-matroid-in-greedy-solving). I posted a comment about the question and flagged as well.

The OP responded with:

> @compass i have solved it before i just ask it here.The solution is this: 1.P is finite as stated in qusetion 2.q has inheritance because when we choose B all of its subset still has at most one member of pi 3.q has substitution property as when we have |A| < |B| then B has some memebers of Pi that are not in A so we can add them to A and still it has at most one member of Pi

Which seemed like an answer to me. So no idea why the question was asked. If this were a more conceptual question, I could see a self-answer as being appropriate, but this is an awfully specific homework-style question with an awfully specific homework-style solution.

I thought nothing of it, but later realized that I had flagged [the same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4243697/amir-veyseh) twice when checking my flag status.

A list of all of his questions appears to all be questions about whether greedy algorithms exist for homework problems, some of which he seems to know how to answer, and others which he has not.

I'm not sure if I should be doing anything in this case. The flags for the two initial questions are already in, but this seems to be a trend with all the user's questions.

I guess my options are:

1. Flag one of the posts for moderator pointing out the user's question history. I seldom use this, and the last time I used it I used it wrong, so I try to make sure it doesn't qualify for any other before using this.
2. Flag the other 2 posts. Doesn't address the issue that this is a trend.
3. No further action.

As such, I'm not sure what I should be doing, if anything, in this case.

Comment: If a user has a history of posting low quality questions then that's what the question ban is there for.  What do you expect a mod to do about a user asking several bad questions in a row?

Comment: @Servy I don't know, hence why I am asking.